# CSS/HTML Dynamically Resizing Iframe through Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

In my HTML code, I'm setting my Iframe width value to 95% of the width. I want the height to dynamically resize according to the set aspect ratio. I have made a javascript script to try the dynamically resizing but when i run my HTML it doesn't resize the height.

Here is my html for the iframe:

```
<div class="video">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <iframe src="https://embed.theguardian.com/embed/video/news/video/2016/dec/27/cassetteboy-remix-the-news-2016-review-special-video" scrolling="no" onload="resizeiframe(this);" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </td>
    </tr>
</div>
```

Here is my css:

```
    .video {

    }
    .video iframe {
        align: center;
        width: 95%;
        margin-top: 180px;
        float: top;
        position: relative;
    }
```

and here is my javascript:

```
<script>
    //this is javascript
    //it is used to dynamically resize the height of the iframes based on screen width
    function resizeiframe(object) {
        //assign the aspect ratio to a variable
        private float aspectratio = (6/19);
        //set the objects height to the object's width multiplied by the aspect ratio
        object.style.height = (object.style.width * aspectratio);
    }
</script>
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Since your css is already in percentages, why do you need to explicitly resize it? Also, doesn't the private float give you errors? Or are you compiling your code? private float x isn't valid javascript variable syntax.

Comment: I changed the private float to var and it still doesnt work.

Comment: object.style.width is undefined, so your height gets set to 0 all the time. Do you have a diff vid btw? copying your code floods me with errors in the bootstrap used by the vid. You might have to have a fixed height to begin with to get this to work. Have you tried using css classes instead fo directly putting a style attribute?

Answer (score 1):

**Two Solutions**

First, you had a few issues with your original JS:

- You were not getting the width of the `iframe` correctly (use `element.offsetWidth` or the like)
- You need to assign the unit when setting a width (`px`, etc.)
- You were typing `aspectratio` incorrectly as `private float` instead of `var` or `private aspectratio: number;` (Typescript)  *-- unless you are using another superset JS language and it wasn't tagged in the question.*

**JavaScript:** (Modification to your original)

```
      function resizeiframe(object) {
          //assign the aspect ratio to a variable
          var aspectratio = (6/19);
          //set the objects height to the object's width multiplied by the aspect ratio
          object.style.height = (object.offsetWidth * aspectratio) + "px";
      }

      // This is just quick and dirty to grab the element -- do something better
      resizeiframe(document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0]);
```

[**Working Plnkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZYoNs6nYjFJiudjmG0VZ?p=preview)

Doing this via JavaScript may also require that you call `resizeiframe` on `window.resize` to compensate for user's resizing of the browser window.

***OR***

This can also be accomplished with a *CSS-Only* solution (no JavaScript needed), if you're not against using `vw` (viewport width units) instead of `px` (pixels).

**CSS:**

```
  iframe {
    width: 95vw;
    height: calc(95vw*(6/19));
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<iframe src="https://embed.theguardian.com/embed/video/news/video/2016/dec/27/cassetteboy-remix-the-news-2016-review-special-video" scrolling="no" onload="resizeiframe(this);" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

[**Working Plnkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/tdzBcngHJYTE08bcxjIF?p=preview)

With this solution, browser resizing is handled *automagically*.

**Note:** In both solutions, I removed `.video` wrapper element to simplify the answer, but this can be easily added back.

Answer (score 0):

You should add px.

```
object.style.height = (object.style.width * aspectratio) + "px";
```